# Feature Create Swift Virtual Network is not allowed for a free trial subscription

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-service-plan

I was trying to create Virtual Network (using #terraform), but this operation failed with error message “Feature Create Swift Virtual Network is not allowed for a free trial subscription”.

Here is the complete Error: creating/updating App Service VNet association between “res-fnc-uat” (Resource Group “res-uat”) and Virtual Network “res-vnet-uat”: web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdateSwiftVirtualNetworkConnectionWithCheck: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 — Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code=”BadRequest” Message=”Feature Create Swift Virtual Network is not allowed for a free trial subscription.” Details=[{“Message”:”Feature Create Swift Virtual Network is not allowed for a free trial subscription.”},{“Code”:”BadRequest”},{“ErrorEntity”:{“Code”:”BadRequest”,”ExtendedCode”:”52018",”Message”:”Feature Create Swift Virtual Network is not allowed for a free trial subscription.”,”MessageTemplate”:”Feature {0} is not allowed for a free trial subscription.”,”Parameters”:[“Create Swift Virtual Network”]}}]

│with module.modules.azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection.network-swiftcon,

│ on ../../modules/networking.tf line 51, in resource “azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection” “network-swiftcon”:
│ 51: resource “azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection” “network-swiftcon” {

I was not aware about the solution.

Comment: " is not allowed for a free trial subscription" - what is not clear about that?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations for trial subscriptions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

For App Services, you can't enable Vnet Integration, for any App Service SKU.

[image]

If you want to test this feature, you need a "Pay as you go" subscription.

Comment: I'm on a "Pay as you go" subscription and am getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75013496/terraform-feature-create-swift-virtual-network-is-not-allowed-for-a-free-trial